# How to change permissions for a single page or story?

Tags: drupal, permissions

In drupal, how can I change the permissions on a single page or story? I want to change one page or story so that only admins can post comments and all users can see those comments but can't post any of their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A module that comes close to solving your problem is [Comment Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/comment_perm), which allows you to set permissions for node types. You should be able to write some custom code, either making your own module entirely or along with the CP module, to change the permission for that particular node.